# magento rest api V1/products endpoint

Tags: magento-2.1, api, rest-api

I use following code to call rest api in magento 2.1.5

```
    $consumerKey = 'aca1rh9env59axm0ob48xfu62t9s4a5e';
    $consumerSecret = 'dgn4y1ejfu9aixb5mrio4kbsor5tq208';
    $accessToken = 'fi5keosdaod7hgqsyhv9i8o2yxvk0dqx';
    $accessTokenSecret = 'ugeovkdcyvl3q2wc0kxjmgiprobtr63g';

    $method = 'GET';
    $url = 'https://dev.devserver.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1';

    $data = [
        //'searchCriteria' => '',
        'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
        'oauth_nonce' => md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),
        'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
        'oauth_token' => $accessToken,
        'oauth_version' => '1.0'
    ];

    $data['oauth_signature'] = $this->sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenSecret);

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                'Authorization: OAuth ' . http_build_query($data, '', ',')
        ]
    ]);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    var_dump($result);

    public function sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $tokenSecret)
    {
        $url = $this->urlEncodeAsZend($url);

        $data = $this->urlEncodeAsZend(http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
        $data = implode('&', [$method, $url, $data]);

        $secret = implode('&', [$consumerSecret, $tokenSecret]);

        return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $secret, true));
    }

    public function urlEncodeAsZend($value)
    {
        $encoded = rawurlencode($value);
        $encoded = str_replace('%7E', '~', $encoded);
        return $encoded;
    }
```

Everything works fine in this case. But if i change url to somethinf like this https://dev.devserver.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=10

i got error: invalid signature. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Great. After several days of heavy debugging solution is found suddenly. I use https://github.com/springimport/magento2-api-v1

Answer (score 1):

Solution came suddenly. It looks like url and params were encoded wrongly. I use this library to ease rest api coding https://github.com/springimport/magento2-api-v1

```
    use springimport\magento2\apiv1\Configuration,
        springimport\magento2\apiv1\ApiFactory;

    ...

    $configuration = new Configuration;
    $configuration->setBaseUri('https://dev.devserver.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1');
    $configuration->setConsumerKey('aca1rh9env59axm0ob48xfu62t9s4a5e');
    $configuration->setConsumerSecret('dgn4y1ejfu9aixb5mrio4kbsor5tq208');
    $configuration->setToken('fi5keosdaod7hgqsyhv9i8o2yxvk0dqx');
    $configuration->setTokenSecret('ugeovkdcyvl3q2wc0kxjmgiprobtr63g');

    $apiFactory = new ApiFactory($configuration);
    $client = $apiFactory->getApiClient();

    $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://dev.devserver.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=10', ['verify' => false]);
    echo $res->getStatusCode();
    // 200
    echo $res->getHeaderLine('content-type');
    // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
    echo $res->getBody();
    die();

    ...
```